# How to check range in a dynamic array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to check a value that is matching some range in an dynamic array.I have a amount for example say `3555`,
I have a array `[1000,2000,999999]`. Normally we can use if statement to check for dynamic range like,

```
if(3555<100)
{
    //do something
}
elseif(3555<2000)
{
    //do something
}
elseif(3555<999999)
{
    //do something
}
```

Condition that I need to implement is that **static amount(3555) is greater that some value and less than some value**,To be more specific
like `Amount < 1000 >2000`
Now I have a dynamic array to feed as input.How could I check for condition that is true and get the array index? Can someone  help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of jQuery for something like that,
a simple way to get what you want is to run you test for each couple value of the range array, and if something match to return the index.

```js
function test(number, ranges) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; ++i) {
    if (number < ranges[i]) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}


var ranges = [1000, 2000, 999999];

console.log(test(3555, ranges));
```

Comment: index that should match is the last one 999999? How to do that?@user3

Comment: return `i+1` instead of `i`, I assumed you wanted the index of the lower bound ;) @Anu

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one?

```
getIndex = function(array, amount) {
for(var i in array.sort()) {
    if(array[i] > amount) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
};
```

This will return the index from the number greater than amount

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/diegopolido/6wuutsk6/

Comment: if 3555 is the input amount it should satisfy 99999. because the value is 3000 and above. Can you please help me?@Diego Polido Santana

Comment: This function will return 2 (the index of  999999). Look at the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate the array like so (this would return the first index where num is greater than the value in the array or -1 if none is found)

```
function amount(array, num) {
    array.forEach(function(val, index){
        if (val < num) {
            return index;
        }
    });
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```js
var arr = [100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 999999];
var min = 1000;
var max = 4010;

var resultingArray = arr.filter(function(val, index, ar) {
  return val < max && val > min;
});

document.write('Result is: ' + resultingArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var theArray = [100,300,800,1000,1300];
var goal = 400;
var nearest= null;
$.each(theArray, function(){
    if (nearest == null || Math.abs(this - goal) < Math.abs(nearest - goal){
        nearest = this;
    }
});
```